# How does this oracle SQL command works?

Tags: sql, oracle, command

I know that, it removes all the duplicated rows, but I can't check it. How is the following piece of code working?

```
DELETE grades 
 WHERE rowid NOT IN (SELECT MAX(rowid) 
                       FROM grades 
                      GROUP BY grades);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, apparently, you have a table `GRADES`, with a column `GRADES`.  The `SELECT` will identify the max rowid per grades (`GROUP BY GRADES`).  This gives you one single row per unique value for GRADES.  Then, the `DELETE` will delete any row that's not in the list of rowids you generated from the `SELECT`.

The end result is, you end up with only one row per unique `GRADES` value.  This means all duplicates will be removed.

Hope that's clear.

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE grades WHERE rowid NOT IN (SELECT MAX(rowid) FROM grades GROUP BY grades);
```

The `ROWID` column is a hash value representing the hash of where the data is being stored. Oracle is used to incremend that value everytime a value is inserted into a table. Therefore, the last one is the maximum.

```
SELECT MAX(rowid) FROM grades GROUP BY grades
```

This query is therefore selecting the last value inserted in the table, and the `group by` allow you to indentify a single value among all same value of `grades`.

```
DELETE grades WHERE ...
```

Finally, you delete all the values that were not selected, that means all the values that are not the last inserted, all duplicates that were formelly inserted.

Comment: ROWID is not a hash. It uniquely identifies the location (e.g. physical address) of a row.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, `rowid` are never duplicated. The `rowid` is the unique (internal) row identifier for Oracle.

Since I imagine the grade tables is not a huge table, and is not involved in foreign key relationship, you could simply do this:

```
create table grades_temp as select distinct * from grades;
delete from grades;
insert into grades select * from grades_temp;
drop table grades_temp;
```

You should also declare a primary key and a unique index on the grades table to avoid future insert of duplicated data.